# Using Multiple Database Resources

Tags: database, resource-model, setup-script

I've been trying to get Magento connecting to two different databases within one module, and I'm running into some trouble. The reason I'm using a second database is to pull in Wordpress content. The funny part is that I'm able to connect to that just fine and pull in my Wordpress content, but my connection to the magento database from within my module, or at least my mysql setup model mapping is not working correctly (unsure which) or else my setup script would run. The end goal is to get that setup script to run and create my table for me. I've deleted the row from core_resource, and it does not seem to ever recreate the row anymore. Here's what I've got:

app/code/local/Company/MyModule/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_mymodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>


        <resources>
            <mymodule_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Company_MyModule</module>
                    <class>Company_MyModule_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_setup>
        </resources>


        <models>
            <!-- This is for our wordpress posts -->
            <mymodule>
                <class>Company_MyModule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mymodule_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </mymodule>
            <mymodule_mysql4>
                <class>Company_MyModule_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <post>
                        <table>wp_posts</table>
                    </post>
                </entities>
            </mymodule_mysql4>


            <!-- This is for our mapping table for related posts onto products -->
            <mymodule_related_posts>
                <class>Company_MyModule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mymodule_related_posts_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </mymodule_related_posts>
            <mymodule_related_posts_mysql4>
                <class>Company_MyModule_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                <entities>
                    <related_posts>
                        <table>company_mymodule_related_posts</table>
                    </related_posts>
                </entities>
            </mymodule_related_posts_mysql4>

        </models>

    <global>

<config>
```

app/etc/local.xml:

```
<config>

    <global>

        <resources>

            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[ommitted]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[ommitted]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[ommitted]></password>
                    <dbname>[ommitted]</dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>


            <mymodule_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>mymodule_database</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_write>
            <mymodule_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>mymodule_database</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_read>
            <mymodule_setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>mymodule_database</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_setup>
            <mymodule_database>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[ommitted]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[ommitted]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[ommitted]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[ommitted]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_database>

        </resources>

    <global>

<config>
```

app/code/local/Company/MyModule/Model/Resource/Mysql4/Setup.php:

```
<?php
class Company_MyModule_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup {

}
```

app/code/local/Company/MyModule/sql/mymodule_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php:

```
<?php
die('running installer');
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company_mymodule_related_posts` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `product_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `project_id` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Please let me know if you spot what I'm doing wrong that's preventing that install script form running. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. It looks like the issue was in my module's config.xml, this section:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_mymodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
```

Should actually have been:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_MyModule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <global>
```

(Notice the capitalization of the module name)